# Как запустить .app с параметры для argv?

Tags: macos, qt, c++

Программу в Mac OS из командной строки запускаю следующим образом:

```
$ open myprogram.app
```

1) Но не могу понять как запустить с параметрами? Если попробовать:

```
$ open myprogram.app arg1 arg2
```

то терминал пишет:

> The file /Documents/Meine Projekt/arg1
> does not exist.

2) Внутри пытаюсь получить строку так:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8(argv[0]);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Точно не уверен, но скорее всего придется долезть до бинарника внутри бандла (бандл хитрый вид папки) и дернуть непосредственно его. Где он конкретно лежит сейчас на вскидку не скажу, но он там по умолчанию всего один исполняемый вроде
2. есть статический метод QCoreApplication::arguments (), возвращающий список аргументов в виде массива строк, только важно помнить что нулевой аргумент у него - имя программы

Comment: Кстати, при помощи `open` вопрос решается так:  

`$ open /path/to/your.app --args arg1 arg2`

Comment: Спасибо, я про этот финт не знал - как-то никогда не нужно было

Answer (score 0):

open myprogram.app arg1 arg2?

Comment: Обновил согласно комментарию.